# Firefox OS (html5,js) vs Android (java) vs IOS (objective-c) In terms of pl and tech use, how can the other is faster?

Tags: firefox, operating-systems, android, ios, mobile-phone

1. How can be one faster than the others, what happens inside their code, is it a matter of the engine they are using? (noob about the gecko, linux kernel thing, educate me)
2. One of the limitations of web-based OS is lack of power/permissions that a native apps had, can this be overcome of an OS like firefox and chrome for mobile?

I just want to understand the code-side on how/why the other can be better than the others..

Comment: Questions about smartphones [aren't on topic SU](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). A pity, because this is a good question that can inspire great answers.

Comment: edited the question. Its really more about the software of those mobile OS isnt it? ^^

Comment: @fireflieslive - I suppose but you are trying to compare a cloud os type design to two mobile operating systems that are not cloud based.  Besides no even aware of any released Firefox OS phones